# passing object as string to delayed job and then desirializing back to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

i started using the delay job gem, and now i am trying to delay a call to a method that accepts an object `{:val=>'my name'}`

my call is like this:

```
User.delay.my_static_method(my_object)
```

this is not allowed because an object can't be saved in the DB
so how do i serialize this object to a string to give to delay, and then back to an object in my method?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're small enough objects, try Ruby's built-in serialisation http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Marshal.html

If you have more complicated serialisation needs than `Marshal`, then something like http://msgpack.org/ could work.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an object's ID to your delay method call, for example. But save given object to DB, or a file before passing it.

Then in your Worker class code you should retrieve given object by ID (if you saved it to DB) or by filename (if you saved it as file).